# Allow user id and password in connection string to access a SQL Server database, but disable that user from connecting to server

Tags: sql-server, web-config

I created a user login in SQL Server and I am using that userid and password in my `web.config`. My problem is that the requirements are: the user defined in the `web.config` should only be able to access the database, but should not be able to use those credentials to logon to the server.

When I change the permissions to "connect", the user is able to login to the server and that is what I do not want and when I change permissions by unticking "connect" the website does not connect. I dont know if I am making sense.

Please help me figure this out

Comment: Create a separate user which is not VM account holder. Hence, it won't be able to login into VM

Answer (score 0):

So this particular user has access to login to windows server as well?

You should change the password from control panel for particular user and this way the user will only have access to the database through the code only.